# ¿Cómo cambiar el número de Post a mostrar en una página Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, post, url

Como usuario, ¿se puede cambiar el número de Post que muestra una página en Wordpress ?

Deseo hacer una búsqueda en una página y el resultado son mas de 300, pero me los muestra en entradas de 10, entonces se pierde mucho tiempo usando el paginador.

¿Alguna forma de que no se límite a 10 resultados?

ojo : esto es como usuario, no soy el desarrollador.

Comment: settings->reading -> num posts

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el número de post debes ir dentro del propio CMS a al archivo 'php' functions.php del tema y ahí de manera sencilla puedes elegir el número de post a visualizar en categorías y búsquedas.

En este código de ejemplo cambio la opción de visualizar a 30 post en las categorías y 50 en los resultados de búsqueda:

```
  function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {
       if ( is_category() )
        $limit = 30;
       elseif ( is_search() )
        $limit = 50;
      else
        $limit = get_option('posts_per_page');
      set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', $limit);
  }
  add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');
```

Dónde he puesto estos números de post, prueba a poner el que tú consideres que es necesario para tu proyecto.